# Truffle test - No events were emitted + TypeError: test.titlePath is not a function

Tags: solidity, testing, unittesting, mocha, truffle-test

```
1) test_initial_badge_creation
    > No events were emitted


  2 passing (2s)
  1 failing


/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/reporters/base.js:178
  failures.forEach(function (test, i) {
           ^
TypeError: test.titlePath is not a function
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/reporters/base.js:230:10
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.exports.list (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/reporters/base.js:178:12)
    at Spec.Base.epilogue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/reporters/base.js:350:10)
    at Runner.emit (events.js:185:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:829:12
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:677:9
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:290:14)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:334:5)
    at runCallback (timers.js:763:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:734:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:716:5)
```

Can somebody explain how the test can fail without emitting an event even tho I have an Assert phrase in it?

```
function test_initial_creation() public{
    A a = A(DeployedAddresses.A());
    B b = B(DeployedAddresses.B());

    a.init(address(b));

    address[] memory adr;
    uint[] memory price;
    (adr, price) = a.getInfo();

    Assert.equal(adr.length, 6, "Initial Info length should be 6");
}
```

Shouldn't it pass or fail with an emitted event?
Also what is the error message from Mocha below?

Comment: Can you post the test code?

Comment: @mirg Sure. Updated with test code